# Heroku fails to perform clockwork delayed tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

I am having a clockwork configuration file(inside the lib folder) that queues another file's methods to perform delayed tasks.

```
require_relative "Adwords/Extractor"
```

It is working fine on my local machine (WEBrick running on win8). However on heroku, it is failing with the following error:

```
 'app[web.1]: /app/lib/clock.rb:5:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /app/li
  b/Adwords/Extractor (LoadError)'
```

The Extractor.rb script is located at the same place as mentioned by the error statement.

Comment: using uppercase names for files is not a best practice in ruby. it's also the case that some operation-systems are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/lib/Adwords/Extractor"
```

use relative path to rails app.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby 1.9.2 or higher no longer make the current directory . part of your LOAD_PATH.

You can get around it by using absolute paths

```
File.expand_path(__FILE__) et al
```

or doing

```
require './filename' (ironically).
```

or by using

```
require_relative 'filename'

require './filename'
```

only works if your script is executed with the working directory set to the same directory that the script resides. This is often not the case in multi-directory projects.